# What do javascript code != -1 do?

Tags: javascript

So I found this and it appears to work fine and is extremely helpful.
I just need to know what code "!= -1" do. It appears the code don't work without it.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">

function validate_input(data){
   var iChars = "!@#$%^&*()+=-[]\\;,./{}|:<>?~_"; /* characters not allowed  */
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (iChars.indexOf(data.charAt(i)) != -1) {
      alert ("Your filename has special characters. \nThese are not allowed.");
    return false;
    }
  }
  if(data.length < 1){
  alert("File Name is required");
    return false;
  }

}

</script>

</head>

<body>
<form action="#" method="Get" onSubmit="return validate_input(document.getElementById('filename').value);">
<input type="text" id="filename" name="filename">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have a look at this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: It checks if the result of `.indexOf()` is `-1`, d'uh. Read the `String.indexOf` documentation.

Comment: Your condition states that if its not equal to -1.

Comment: I find `>= 0` to scan slightly better than `!= -1`. YMMV.

Comment: `!=` is a comparison operator and means "not equal". It compares the left hand side with the right hand side and returns `true` if both values are different (after type coercion), otherwise `false`. `-1` is actually the number literal `1` and the unary minus operator `-`. The number literal creates the number value `1` and the unary minus operator negates the value. I recommend to read about the basics of JavaScript: http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter2.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`indexOf` returns `-1` when the string is not found.

```
"abc".indexOf("def"); // -1
"abc".indexOf("ab"); // 0
"abc".indexOf("c"); // 2
```

In a nutshell, you code checks if any of `iChars` characters are present.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Then "!= -1" should stand for "not not found", because using only == should corespond as different numbers, so its easier to tell what we dont want than what we want.

Answer (score 0):

Its stands for ***"not equals to -1"***.
And in your case whole condition checks whether char at position **i** is special character. Function [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) returns -1 if there is no such item in correspondent array.

Answer (score 0):

IndexOf will return -1 if the string was not found in the object.